# Getting Unauthorized access to web api when called from code behind file

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using the GuestController controller class. I going to access this GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId api method from the ajax as well as from the code behind file. This method returns proper result while ajax call but in code behind getting error with "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'"

Api controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class GuestController : ApiController
{

    public int GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId(int roomId)
    {
        return GuestManager.GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId(roomId);
    } // GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function getGuestBookingIdByRoomId(roomId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _pageURL + "/api/Guest/GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId",
        type: "GET",
        data: { roomId: roomId },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (bookingId) {
            if (bookingId != undefined && bookingId != null && bookingId > 0) {  
                _receiverBookingId = bookingId;
            } else {
                // Do Nothing                             
            }
        },
    });
}
```

api call from code behind:

```
private int GetReceiverBookingId(int roomId)
{
    int receiverBookingId = 0;
    // Create object of http client 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // assign Base address
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + Request.Url.Authority);
    // Set request header
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    // build web api url
    var url = "/api/Guest/GetGuestBookingIdByRoomId?roomId=" + roomId;
    // Call web api method
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // If web api call is successfull  
    {
        receiverBookingId = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>().Result;
    }
    else
    {

    }       
     return receiverBookingId;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of autentication you are using?

Comment: I am using "Forms" authentication

Comment: try changing your `httpclient` like this `HttpClientHandler hndlr = new HttpClientHandler();
hndlr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hndlr);`

Comment: Why call the API from the code behind? To do that you will need to capture the authentication cookie from the client and pass it to the API assuming you are sharing authentication between WebForms and Web API of course.

Comment: thanks gabriel. can you elaborate how to pass authentication cookie to web api method with sample code?